# Formatting hours and minutes in django backend

Tags: python, django, datetime, format

I have a method in my django app (1.8).

From date recived from **date_start** field: `2017-01-26 18:00:00+00:00` I want to get hours and minutes. But my code didn't works:

```
@property
def time(self):
    return '{%H:%M}'.format(self.date_start)
```

Comment: The strftime function in the standard Python modules time and/or datetime should help.

Comment: "doesn't work" is the worst possible description of a problem. Please explain what happens with all relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `self.start_date` yields a `datetime.datetime` object, you want to use `self.start_date.stftime("{%M:%S}")` - example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("{%M:%S}")
'{31:52}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this. The reason your code doesn't work* is that you need your format string to match the *whole* string representation of the date. After that, you can extract the specific date/time components that you need.

In the code below I forgo the need to use any format strings by using a third-party library called `dateutil.parser` that @asongtoruin told me about a few hours ago.

```
import dateutil.parser

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, date_start):
        self.date_start = date_start

    @property
    def time(self):
        date = dateutil.parser.parse(self.date_start)
        return '{:02}:{:02}'.format(date.hour, date.minute)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo('2017-01-26 18:00:00+00:00')
    print(foo.time)  # 18:00
```

* Actually I'm making the assumption that `self.date_start` is a plain string, since you're unclear both on what type of data it is and what problem you're getting.